# How To Tracking URL Link in other website

Tags: php, javascript, external, tracking, trace

I want to know how to programming the script for **tracking** purpose.

Such as I put the link on my blog, and I **can know which IP or which website** is **using my URL Link** on their website?

I have a live price url that retrieved from my own database.

E.g. www.example.com/live_price.php

It is only display data in table format, where data are dynamically selecting from my database.

This URL Link exposes to other people put onto their website. Example in iFrame or other method to exactly display the link on website.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't.

You can't know which website uses your link because the person hitting the link is the home user, not your website.

A home user hits http://mywebsite.com/ which returns an HTML document containing a link to an image off your website. From your point of view, you just see a user downloading the image off your website. There is no way for you to find out that he heard of the link from http://mywebsite.com/.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can check the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to see where a user is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can try $_SERVER vars

Using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` you can see the ip of the system from which your site is being addressed.
`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you can check the user agent .

check for more $_SERVER vars [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)